# How to get user details in asp.net Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net

I am using windows Authentication and accessing user name as.

```
IIdentity winId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
string name = winId.Name;
```

but i want to get other details like User full name and EmailID.

Comment: Are you using memebership provider in your application?

Comment: no, my app. is on intranet so using windows authentication.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you're on a windows network, then you need to query the Active directory to search for user and then get it's properties such as the email

Here is an example function `DisplayUser` that given an `IIdentity` on a windows authenticated network, finds the user's `email`:

```
public static void Main() {
    DisplayUser(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
    Console.ReadKey();    
}

public static void DisplayUser(IIdentity id) {    
    WindowsIdentity winId = id as WindowsIdentity;
    if (id == null) {
        Console.WriteLine("Identity is not a windows identity");
        return;
    }

    string userInQuestion = winId.Name.Split('\\')[1];
    string myDomain = winId.Name.Split('\\')[0]; // this is the domain that the user is in
     // the account that this program runs in should be authenticated in there                    
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + myDomain);
    DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

    adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" + userInQuestion + "))";
    SearchResult userObject = adSearcher.FindOne();
    if (userObject != null) {
        string[] props = new string[] { "title", "mail" };
        foreach (string prop in props) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", prop, userObject.Properties[prop][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

gives this:
[image]

Edit: If you get 'bad user/password errors'
**The account that the code runs under must have access the users domain**. If you run code in asp.net then the web application must be run under an application pool with credentials with domain access. See [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) for more information

Comment: thanks, but ... I am using windows authentication so my purpose is: there is a usl "http://ipAddress/myApp/home.aspx" now when use open it on intra net then in screen we will see His login name, Full name and emailid. He will not do anythink else. Now come to ur code... how will we set "myPassword".

Comment: Alt+PrintScreen will capture only selected windows so you will not have background noise on the resulting screenshot

Comment: @Preet: in local (bebug) it is working fine but in iis its giving error...System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a `MyCustomIdentity` by overriding from `IIdentity` and add your own properties etc.

Answer (score -2):

Cast it to the specific Identity, for example `WindowsIdentity`

Comment: i think u have not read my question. I need full name and emailid. We can not get these details by WindowsIdentity.