# Validate Credentials and Redirect to given page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am sending an email to an external user with the link.

This is how my url looks. "www.Details.aspx?Id=1234".

When user clicks on Url, I want to him to go Login page first, validate his credentials and then redirect to the given page.

How can I do this using Windows Authentication ? How to give URl ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows Authentication, you don't need a login page.

You need to put this in your web.config (inside system.web):

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

If your website is in IIS, you need to configure the site so that it uses windows authentication.

Comment: Maybe I need to add that if you need the connected user's email, you need to query Active Directory for that with the current user's name.
Here's a link for that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986198/how-to-get-user-details-in-asp-net-windows-authentication

Comment: Hello, what about forms authentication ?

Comment: In your question you ask "how can I do this using Windows Authentication".

If you are using Form Authentication, @landsteven answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ASP.NET Web page named **Login.aspx** in your application.

**Note:** By default, ASP.NET forms authentication is configured to use a page named Login.aspx. You can change the default login page name in the Web.config file for your application using the LoginUrl property.

From the **How to: Create an ASP.NET Login Page** MSDN article:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178331(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178331%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)